# How is the memory allocated in an AVR?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, c, memory, flash

I'm writing a program for the AVR microcontroller, and my code experiments has led me to both confusion and discovery. Here is first code:

```
void USART_PutByte (int8_t byte)
{
uint8_t tempTxTail = (USART_TxTail + 1) & USART_BUFFER_MASK;            //  Creating temporary incremented tail (for interruptions)
while(USART_TxHead == tempTxTail);                                      //  Wait for free space in the buffer
USART_TxTail = tempTxTail;                                              //  Now update tail
USART_TransmitBuffer[USART_TxTail] = byte;                          //  And put byte in the Transmit buffer, which will handle the interrupt

UCSRB |= 1 << UDRIE;                                                    //  Enable interrupt handler
}
```

And the second code, which led me into confusion, but, nevertehless, pleasantly surpised:

```
void USART_PutByte (int8_t byte)
{
uint8_t tempTxTail = (USART_TxTail + 1) & USART_BUFFER_MASK;            //  Creating temporary incremented tail (for interruptions)
while(USART_TxHead == tempTxTail);                                      //  Wait for free space in the buffer
USART_TxTail = tempTxTail;                                              //  Now update tail
USART_TransmitBuffer[tempTxTail] = byte;                                //  And put byte in the Transmit buffer, which will handle the interrupt

UCSRB |= 1 << UDRIE;                                                    //  Enable interrupt handler
}
```

The second code is lighter than the first by 4 kb. But the difference only is in penultimate line. And I would like to understand, because of what the second code takes less memory, than the first, in order to use this understanding for my projects. Is it a feature of C language, or a microcontroller? Or does it depend on the case?
P.S.: Sorry, if gramatical mistakes were made, I learn English. :-)

Comment: Can you highlight  the difference between the codes? I can't spot any using my eyes and I am not up to running `diff` on that. Update: Ok, I see it. Doesn't make much sense without more context. Your best bet would be to look at the generated `map` file.

Comment: You could have a look at the generated assembly code. The answer is there, for sure. On our side, we, however, can only make unverifiable hypothesis with the information you gave.

Comment: Nothing in the code posted will obviously take 4kb of memory on any microcontroller. The question doesn't make sense and the problem is located elsewhere. In case of AVR, one likely culprit for any form of problem is the dysfunctional "Harvard architecture".

Answer (score 1):

I've been programming in C since 1978, when working on the Unix kernel, and have used it every year since then. So I know the language pretty well, including being able to generate assembly code for it "on the fly."

I can tell you that there simply isn't enough information provided.

One possibility that comes to my mind is that you didn't measure the "4 kb difference" correctly. I can't tell, because you don't disclose how you arrived at that figure. But I have to consider it as a logical possibility, since I don't think you are an expert.

If you did get that figure right, then it's not possible to tell from the code you provided here. I did find some code on the web that provides sample code that "appears" to be similar to me. I might assume that your code looks like the samples. But the samples I saw were NOT actually library code source and I can't tell if you copied stuff from sample code or if you are using some library. This might matter. So again, I don't have enough information.

One suggestion I see here is about the *volatility* of the variable you used. Certainly, since that appears to be the only change you allowed us to see (and you assure it is *is* the only change, I think), it's natural for us to focus on that difference. But it is completely insufficient to explain the change in the footprint you mentioned. A volatile variable cannot be *optimized* in certain ways (it's a complex enough set of rules that I don't want to belabor it here.) But in no conceivable way can I imagine a C compiler that could be so fundamentally flawed in its design that it could explain that.

(Except in one possible case -- it's possible that your compiler is the "free version" of an "expensive commercial version" and that they've intentionally done something to it that you've triggered. But with the AVR, I don't think this is a possible explanation. So I'm not going there with this.)

This leaves open some questions:

1. Are you using library code or did you get your code from one of the several example code sets I saw that included a main() function and laid out an approach that you copied and modified? If you did copy out some code, why not provide us with the entire context? It may matter.
2. Differences like the size you saw often are a matter of misinterpretation. I'd like to know how you actually *measured* this difference. Discuss your method and your thinking about it. Did you look at the map file to work this out? If so, why not include the two different map files in your question?
3. Differences like this may be whether or not certain library code was inserted (linked), or not. This might happen if you made ***other*** changes in your code that you believed were ***unrelated*** but actually are the reason for the difference and instead you accidentally hid those from our view. For example, if you added some code to use a printf() function, you might imagine that has nothing to do with your observation. Yet perhaps this was the first use of it and including it meant that an entire library of code was installed by the linker because it needed to do so. I need your assurances that this isn't part of the problem and that your presented difference is the ***only*** actual difference in the code.
4. Differences like this also can be the matter of whether or not an array is added to the code at compile time vs using heap space for it. Or it can be about a linker "spill" out of one code/data segment into another one (depending on the linker rules.)

I think probably the single most important things are the following:

- Assure us that this change you presented is the ***only*** change. I could assume from your writing that this is so. And it would be reasonable to do so. But I want your explicit assurances. Not assumptions.
- Provide the two different map files generated by the linker. If you don't know how to do that, figure it out and produce them with as much detail as the linker options permit. Pretty much everything will be there and the rest "will just follow from there."

Answer (score 0):

As speculation, the compiler will probably allocate a register for tempTXTail instead of storing the variable in memory.  In the AVR architecture (and most others) this makes dereferenced access using this variable (like the array access you used) significantly faster and uses fewer instructions.

Was the function marked as inline (or optimized to be so)?  If there are lots of references to the function this could explain the code size difference.

To find out, look at the map file and the assembler output of the compiler.  A 4K difference should be easy to spot.

Answer (score 0):

`USART_TxTail` is `volatile` so the compiler needs to generate a store followed by a load instead of assuming it has the value that was just assigned to it.